# Git : Confuse after merge

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I am new to git. Recently, I merged some code from `feature` to `master` branch. After merging my .gitignore file looks like this

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
gen/
bin/
=======
gen/
>>>>>>> master
```

Now my question is

1. If I want to change content of that file, should I follow any special instruction or just normally I can change the file and commit ?
2. What are the meaning of those sign `<<<<<<< HEAD` `>>>>>>> master` ?
3. If I remove head and master from the file. Will it generate any error ?

Comment: BTW, If I'm not wrong you merge feature to master, not master to feature now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows what was in your current `HEAD`, and what was in the `master` branch.

If you want to choose what was in the HEAD you should leave only

```
gen/
bin/
```

in that file. If you decide to choose what was in `master` you should ahce only

```
gen/
```

in that file.

You also may need to write here anything else. After merge this file will look like you commit it now.

I believe it's no practical case when you will not deleted special lines as

```
=======
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the last line. Will you please describe.

Comment: @user2579475, I believe it's easier to understand now